# Issue with the insert statement using quoting factor in oracle

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle11g, insert

I am struck with a oracle insert statement. I have a table called as "BATCH" it has two columns S_NO, DATA , I have a string value where it has all the special character's in it . for example in the column "DATA" i am having value like this (This is the important [batch]'s which need to be inserted). I use quoting factor for var char values basically.

```
insert into BATCH(SNO,DATA)
VALUES(1,q'[This is the important [batch]'s which need to be inserted]') ;
```

When i fire this insert statement the oracle is throwing an error called as missing comma. The reason is in the string (q'[This is the important [batch]'s]') after the word called as batch the next to that word i have (]') , which is indicating oracle that that is the end of the column data . How can i handle this sort of data if i use quoting factor .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: *batches*, surely? (If so, *These are the important batches*. I think I'd prefer *that* to *which* here, too.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change quote delimiter:

```
insert into BATCH(SNO,DATA)
VALUES(1,q'{This is the important [batch]'s which need to be inserted}');
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f2b4a584f7d402b688f5d69d0445cbb3)**

> *If i have data like this (This is the important [batch}'s which need to be inserted) then oracle is throwing error as invalid string*

Then you need to change quote delimeter to character that is least likely to be part of original string like `~|^` or any other that is suitable for you.

```
insert into BATCH(SNO,DATA)
VALUES(1,Nq'|This is the important [batch]'s which need to be inserted}|') ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your swift response . If i have data like this (This is the important [batch}'s which need to be inserted) then oracle is throwing error as invalid string .

Comment: @SanthoshPogaku you can chose from a wide range of quote delimiters. [See documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-1824CBAA-6E16-4921-B2A6-112FB02248DA).